# MacOS Catalina: Symbol not found: _PQsslAttribute

Tags: python, postgresql, macos-catalina

I uninstalled Old PgSQL 9 and installed the latest one PgSQL12 app. When I am trying to import `psycopg2` I am getting the following error:

```
>>> import psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PQsslAttribute
  Referenced from: /Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
 in /Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

Comment: I'm getting a similar error but the missing symbol is `_PQencryptPasswordConn`. Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: I am also getting ```_PQencryptPasswordConn```. After using the ```install_name_tool``` method described in the answer it resolves it. However, if I later do a ```pip uninstall -r requirements.txt``` and add some new package dependencies and then ```pip install -r requirements.txt``` again I have to repeat the process. In my case, I have /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib linking to /usr/lib/libpq.5.5.dylib possibly from old pgSQL 9 or psycopg2-binary....I wonder if it is possible for pscopg2 devs to refactor so that the package remembers the location of lib deps it was built with from pg_config?

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error message (Python3, MacOS 10.14.6) and was able to fix it by doing the following:

> sudo install_name_tool -change libpq.5.dylib /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6//lib/libpq.5.dylib /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages /psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
>
> sudo install_name_tool -change libssl.1.1.dylib /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6//lib/libssl.1.1.dylib /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
>
> sudo install_name_tool -change libcrypto.1.1.dylib /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6//lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so

You'll need to adjust your path names (obviously), both for the python site-packages directory, and the directory where the Postgres .dylib libraries above live. Also, the name of the _psycopg*.so library may/will likely be different on your system.
No promises that it'll solve it for you (also obviously :)
Good luck!